# Getting issue with CComboBox MFC control

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I have a combobox in MFC with dropdown property.

When I open a dialog which is having this combobox, then the text in that combobox is highlighted. When I click on it, just next to the last character in edit field of this combo box and suppose I insert a charater C, its get written at end, but the cursor moves to the beginning.

This is happening just once, again if I move the cursor to end and start writing, everything is working just fine.

When the focus is lost, and again edit it cause the above mentioned problem.

Also in code there is not any special handling for this control.

I am not getting, why this is happening?

Any advice or suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: What does the MESSAGE_MAP have for the combobox control id?

Comment: it's id is "8002", handling only one message "ON_CBN_SELCHANGE"

Comment: is it an owner draw combo?

Comment: No, it's not of type ownerdraw

Answer (score 0):

You may try this in handler for ON_CBN_EDITUPDATE of your combo box-

{

```
DWORD dwSel =  m_mycombo.GetEditSel();
// Only do this if no characters are selected
if( LOWORD( dwSel ) != LOWORD( dwSel ) ) return;

// code you have added handler for

m_mycombo.SetEditSel( LOWORD( dwSel ), LOWORD( dwSel ) );
```

}